# System.InvalidOperationException : Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, marionette: false}

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run my `Selenium` C# automated test using `Grid`.
When i run the test I get the error:

```
Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, marionette: false, platform: WINDOWS}
```

I have `chromedriver.exe` in the following directory:

```
F:\Selenium Projects\C#\Grid practice\automation\
```

I have set the path for Environment Variables from System, Control Panel to the path:

```
F:\Selenium Projects\C#\Grid practice\automation\
```

My code snippet is:

```
public class Browsers : DriverClass
{
    public IWebDriver LaunchBrowser(string browser)
    {
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "chrome":
                GoToChromeBrowser("chrome");
                break;

            case "firefox":
                GoToFirefoxBrowser();
                break;

            case "ie":
                GoToIeBrowser();
                break;

            case "edge":
                GoToEdgeBrowser();
                break;

            case "remote":
                GoToRemoteBrowser();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("did not find browser type selected");
        }
        return Driver;
    }
}
```

The method `GoToChromeBrowser()`:

```
public void GoToChromeBrowser(string BrowserType)
{
    switch (BrowserType)
    {
        case "firefox":
            Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case "chrome":
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
            cap.SetCapability("marionette", false);
            cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
            Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
            break;                    
    }
}
```

To start the Hub I use the command in CMD:

```
java -jar F:\Selenium\Server\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub
```

To register the node I use the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome version=ANY, maxInstances=5, platform=WINDOWS" -port 5566
```

The hub has started fine and the node is registered. No errors there.
Why am I getting the error when I run my test in Visual Studio?
What am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you got marionette driver set to false? If you're testing on Chrome you will be using Chromedriver, I would just remove it. Also, I presume your node is a Windows machine and has Chrome installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebClient* i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the presence of undefined **capability** for **ChromeDriver** as follows :

- You have invoked `SetCapability()` with **"marionette", false**, but *ChromeDriver* doesn't supports any such capability as **marionette**.
- The capability **marionette** is used by *GeckoDriver* and as you are using **selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar** you have to mandatorily use *GeckoDriver* which by default sets **`marionette`** as **true**. If you forcefully set **`marionette`** as **false**, *GeckoDriver* will throw an *exception*.
- As @NareshChaurasia pointed out while you initiate the *Selenium Hub Node* you have to pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* as follows :

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=F:/Selenium Projects/C#/Grid practice/automation/chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.100:4444/grid/register
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Specify the location of driver while starting your node.

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:/nchaurasia/Automation-Architect/connect2tech.in-SeleniumWebDriver3.x_2/driver/chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/
```

Comment: That does not work for me.  The node won't register to the hub with that command.  Removing Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=<path to chromedriver.exe> the node registers fine.

Comment: Can you tell what error you are getting. Make use you use -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=<path to chromedriver.exe>.

The - (hyphen) is important. It is used to pass argument to Java.

Comment: The error I get is Error: Could not find or load main class Browsers\chromedriver.exe

Comment: chromedriver.exe I have placed in my projects folder and I have also placed it in F:\Selenium Browsers\chromedriver.exe  I have also set the path for the environment variable