# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities error within Docker

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I m running the acceptance tests and facing the following errors in my system only, this is working fine inside my other team systems. I'm using a selenium webdriver inside my docker container, it was working fine on my PC as well but don't know why suddenly it started throwing these errors.

Error stacktrace:

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: [], prefs: {intl.accept_languages: en}}, javascriptEnabled: true, version: }
E       Stacktrace:
E           at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:118)
E           at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:85)
E           at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost (DriverServlet.java:69)
E           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:707)
E           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:865)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:535)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:146)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:548)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:257)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1595)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:255)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1340)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:203)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:473)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1564)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:201)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1242)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:144)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:503)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:364)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:260)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:305)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:103)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask (EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run (EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
E           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: WebDriverException
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was docker is not getting chrome properly, so I just removed the image locally (selenium hub and node chrome) and just download then again and it works!

```
docker rmi {imageId}
```

Comment: Technically there can't be anything as _not getting chrome properly_. This answer is the verbose form of the [other canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972291/7429447) answer.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium you're right, but in my case, I solved this issue as I posted the answer... as I mentioned it was working fine suddenly it started crashing

Comment: maybe someone will face the same issue so mine and yours answer can help them :)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: [], prefs: {intl.accept_languages: en}}, javascriptEnabled: true, version: }
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session and the version of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) can't be detected possibly due to the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.1.2***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v98.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.48/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=98* (as per [chromedriver=98.0.4758.48 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.48/notes.txt)).

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to my_ip:5555 [/my_ip] failed: Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991722/7429447)
- [System.InvalidOperationException : Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, marionette: false}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154919/7429447)

Comment: I just posted the answer, please check.. just for your information.. thanks